# Mocking classes with Jest

Tags: class, ecmascript-6, mocking, jestjs

Given I have a class that calls a function `doStuff` like so:

```
const myService = require(`./myService`),
    service = new myService();

exports.doStuff = async (callback) => {
    try {
        const data = await service.doOtherStuff(); //I want to mock this

        return callback(null, data);
    } catch (err) {
        callback(new Error(` > feed failed for ${key}, error: ${err}`));
    }
};
```

my tests work like this:

```
const myClass = require(`../index`);
jest.mock(`./../myService`, () => {
    return function() {
        return {
            doOtherStuff: () => {
                return 1;
            }
        };
    };
});

describe(`service-tests - index`, () => {
        test(`doStuff and test otherStuff`, async () => {
            const result = await myClass.doStuff((err, data) => {
                return data;
            });

            expect(result).toBe(1);
        });
});
```

And my service:

```
class myService{
    constructor() {
        //Do constructor stuff
    }

    async doOtherStuff() {
        //Do other stuff
    }
```

This works but now I just have my mock on this file and not by test.
What I need is to have my mock be changable test by test but cannot seem to figure out how this works together with require.

I tried just doing `jest.mock('./../myService')` and have the `mockImplementation` on the `beforeAll` but that will keep my function in mocked as the automatic mock it seems, returning **undefined**

Anyone ever done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mock a method within a class, which it looks like you're doing, I would suggest you use [jest.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname). It's simple, and you can mock the return value to be whatever you want per test.

```
const myClass = require('../index');
const myService = require('../myService');

describe('service-tests - index', () => {

  let doOtherStuffMock;
  beforeAll(() => {
    doOtherStuffMock = jest.spyOn(myService.prototype, 'doOtherStuff');
  });

  it('mocks doOtherStuff one way', async () => {
    doOtherStuffMock.mockResolvedValue('I am a mocked value');
    const result = await myClass.doStuff((err, data) => data);
    expect(result).toBe("I am a mocked value");
  });

  it('mocks doOtherStuff another way', async () => {
    doOtherStuffMock.mockResolvedValue('I am DIFFERENT mocked value');
    const result = await myClass.doStuff((err, data) => data);
    expect(result).toBe('I am DIFFERENT mocked value');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I'll leave this answer here since both of these approaches work and they can be useful...

...but for this particular case @Daniel is right, mocking the prototype method is easiest

---

An easy way to handle this is to mock `myService.js` as a singleton...

...then you can grab the mock function for `doOtherStuff` and change it per test:

```
const myClass = require(`../index`);

jest.mock(`../myService`, () => {
  const doOtherStuff = jest.fn();  // <= create a mock function for doOtherStuff
  const result = { doOtherStuff };
  return function() { return result; };  // <= always return the same object
});
const doOtherStuff = require('./myService')().doOtherStuff;  // <= get doOtherStuff

describe(`service-tests - index`, () => {

  test(`doStuff and test otherStuff`, async () => {
    doOtherStuff.mockReturnValue(1);  // <= mock it to return something
    const result = await myClass.doStuff((err, data) => data);
    expect(result).toBe(1);  // Success!
  });

  test(`doStuff and test otherStuff`, async () => {
    doOtherStuff.mockReturnValue('something else');  // <= mock it to return something else
    const result = await myClass.doStuff((err, data) => data);
    expect(result).toBe('something else');  // Success!
  });
});
```

---

It also works to auto-mock `myService.js` and use `mockImplementation`...

...but since `index.js` creates a `myService` instance *as soon as it runs* you have to make sure the mock is in place *before* you require `index.js`:

```
jest.mock(`../myService`);  // <= auto-mock
const myService = require('../myService');
const doOtherStuff = jest.fn();
myService.mockImplementation(function() { return { doOtherStuff }; });

const myClass = require(`../index`);  // <= now require index

describe(`service-tests - index`, () => {

  test(`doStuff and test otherStuff`, async () => {
    doOtherStuff.mockReturnValue(1);  // <= mock it to return something
    const result = await myClass.doStuff((err, data) => data);
    expect(result).toBe(1);  // Success!
  });

  test(`doStuff and test otherStuff`, async () => {
    doOtherStuff.mockReturnValue('something else');  // <= mock it to return something else
    const result = await myClass.doStuff((err, data) => data);
    expect(result).toBe('something else');  // Success!
  });
});
```

Comment: Aaaah yes I see, okay this was a bit more of a brain twister getting this one. Thank you too sir!